# How do I make a Google Chrome bookmarklet that fills a spot in a URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

So there's a website I have to frequently interact with. The interface is kind of a pain so I'm trying to figure out a way around that by just changing the URL to what I want to input. I think I've almost got it... although I'm not the best at Javascript and it's been a while.

Example: 
www.examplewebsite.com/status/[spot I want to enter something]/blahblahblah/

What I've got so far is able to fill in the blank spot, but I'm not sure how to go about keeping the stuff that goes after it, cause it freaks the website out if it's gone.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
javascript:void(location.href='URL goes here'+window.prompt("enter search",""));
```

I tried

```
javascript:void(location.href='URL goes here'+window.prompt("enter search","")+href='URL continues here');
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Define "didn't work"? what happened?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, when I tried to use the second javascript bookmarklet that I made it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
javascript:void(location.href='URL goes here'+window.prompt("enter search","")+'URL continues here');
```

Answer (score 3):

## Consider a custom search engine instead of a bookmarklet.

Right-click the Chrome address bar and select *"Edit search engines..."*.
In the *"Other search engines"* area, click *"Add"*.
Give your "search engine" a name and an easy-to-type keyword, like `pain`.
The URL of your new search engine is `www.examplewebsite.com/status/%s/blahblahblah/`.
*"Add"* it.

Now you can type `pain mysearchterm` directly into the address bar and you'll be taken to `www.examplewebsite.com/status/mysearchterm/blahblahblah/`.

Comment: That's interesting, I wasn't aware that I could do that. I will have to mess around with that some more. If I could mark two things as answers I would mark this one as well.